# Unit tests for std::map

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, stl, stdmap

Does anyone know where I can find unit tests that will test `std::map`?

The reason I ask is because I have written a class that acts as a replacment for `std::map` and has virtually all the same functionality, so unit tests for `std::map` will be suitable for my class, too.

Of course, I can write my own, but if someone has already written extensive tests for this then that would save me a lot of time and would hopefully cover things that I might have missed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you write a replacement for it? Any sane test would report "test failed: `std::map` already exists, you're reinventing the wheel, stop wasting your time"

Comment: Because the replacement for it has different semantics (trades logarithmic insertion times for contiguous memory allocation). It's not identical, but has the same interface so the tests for map will be 99% applicable to this new container.

Comment: you probably dont care now, but future readers might wanna check out boost flat map.

Comment: @jalf Sometimes you need an `intervalmap`, but it's missing in the STL, so you re-implement everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While i don't know how much is needed to use them stand-alone, you could take a look at [libstdc++' testsuite](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/23_containers/map/).

Comment: Things moved around a bit in the gcc.gnu.org repo, you might have to search a bit. Or take a look at the [libc++ tests](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/test/std/containers/unord/unord.map/)

Answer (score 3):

Try to find it in open source library implementations like:

[libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/)
[libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The book [The C++ Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134376331) by Plauger et al provides code for a sample STL implementation, with test code for all types. I don't know from memory if the code is available on-line though.